# Walkthrough / tooltip / demo for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, tooltip, demo, walkthrough

I've got an app that appeals to an older demographic.  The interface is simple but with some custom controls where a simple graphic is not completely self explanatory (save to playlist, sort by genre for example).

I've seen plenty of apps with great first run walkthroughs (examples [here](http://mobile-patterns.com/edu)) but don't know if there are some existing libraries out there.

Your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I can't figure out what your question is. Can you state more explicitly what you are asking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found [CMPopTipView](https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView) that, while it doesn't fit my needs completely may be of use to those that are looking to pop a tool tip every now and then.

Comment: Does Apple approve aapp with CMPopTipView ? Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Most of these overlays/walkthroughs can be accomplished by adding a subview to the main window of your app. There are some edge cases to take into account, but for the most part, you need to simply grab a reference to the key window with

```
UIWindow* keyWindow;

keyWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
```

You then would add your overlay view as a subview with:

```
[keyWindow addSubview:anOverlayView];
```

Handling taps to dismiss the overlay can be done with a tap gesture recognizer.

Comment: I guess I was looking for a bit more WOW.  Something like CMPopTipView on github.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to create a click-through demo which runs in the browser and on mobile devices, [AppDemoStore](http://www.appdemostore.com) is the right tool for you. You just have to upload some relevant app screenshots, add hotspots for the navigation between the screens and callouts for explanations. It takes only a couple of minutes and it's free.
Regards,
Daniel